# affine 3D transformation reconstruction

Tags: affine-geometry, rigid-transformation

How can we get the affine 3D matrix in case we have the 3D rotation matrix, the 3D translation vector, the scale factors and the shearing factors?

A = SHEARING (4,4) * ScaleMatrix (4,4) * RotationMatrix(4,4) + T(4,1)

is that accurate?

Comment: If you do rotation and translation, you might want to use a $4\times 4$ matrix.

Comment: @KittyL, right, but I want to know how to compute it?

Comment: It also depends on the order you want to do these transformations.

Comment: @KittyL, what is the common order used to compute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, let 
$$R=\begin{pmatrix}r_{11}&r_{12}&r_{13}\\
r_{21}&r_{22}&r_{23}\\
r_{31}&r_{32}&r_{33}\end{pmatrix}$$
 be the $3\times 3$ rotation matrix, 
$$\vec{t}=\begin{pmatrix}t_1\\t_2\\t_3\end{pmatrix}$$ be the $3\times 1$ translation vector, $s$ be the scale factor. If the order is rotation, translation, then scaling, the matrix should be
$$A=s\begin{pmatrix}r_{11}&r_{12}&r_{13}&t_1\\
r_{21}&r_{22}&r_{23}&t_2\\
r_{31}&r_{32}&r_{33}&t_3\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

If otherwise, the order is rotation, scaling, then translation, the matrix should be

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}sr_{11}&sr_{12}&sr_{13}&t_1\\
sr_{21}&sr_{22}&sr_{23}&t_2\\
sr_{31}&sr_{32}&sr_{33}&t_3\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then 
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1'\\x_2'\\x_3'\\1\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks  for your detailed answer